# Why is Brain.js LSTM producing a random category?

Tags: javascript, json, machine-learning, lstm, brain.js

Here is a piece of my JavaScript code that iterates through my JSON file. It should predict what category it is based on the text given ('net income'). The output is categories that is not in the JSON file. The output should only be based on categories in the JSON file.

```
const brain = require('brain.js');
const data = require('./balancesheet.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const network = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();

const trainingData = data.map(item => ({
    input: item.text,
    output: item.category
}));

network.train(trainingData, {
    iterations: 10
});

const output = network.run('net income');

console.log(`Category: ${output}`);
```

JSON data. There is around 1000 records and 20 different categories.

```
[
    {
       "text":"operating surplus",
       "category":"current year profits"
    },
    {
       "text":"net income",
       "category":"current year profits"
    },
    {
       "text":"other liabilities",
       "category":"accounts payable (non-current)"
    },
    {
       "text":"income advance",
       "category":"income in advance"
    },

*Continues for 1000 records...*
```

Outputs such as

*2000 iterations*

```
Category: retaicometrses
```

*5000 iterations*

```
Category: curued expenses current)
```

These categories are not in the JSON file and are randomly generated. This is bad. The input of 'net income' should produce a category only given in the JSON file.

Comment: I made the same error: LSTM generates a text, it does not classify (categorize).
And I can't figure out how to classify with a LSTM.
I think we should vectorize the text input (depending on the number of possibilities, either by having one input node per text, either by using a word embedding algorithm).